# MaxLength property has no effect when setting text in code

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I noticed that when I set the MaxLength property of an Edit or DBEdit control, this does not stop me from putting text on the control larger than the MaxLength in code.

When I set the MaxLength = 12 for example, then

- I cannot enter a longer value using the keyboard
- I cannot paste a longer text using copy/paste

but I can do this :

```
Edit1.Text := '012345678901234567890123456789'
```

Is this normal behaviour ? Is this also so in Delphi Tokyo ?
And more important, is there an easy way to prevent this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same in 10.2. Tokyo. The property `TEdit.Text` is inherited unchanged from `TControl` (through `TCustomEdit` and `TWinControl`). And `TControl.SetText` does not know anything about `MaxLength`, so it does not limit the text length. It indirectly issues a `CM_TEXTCHANGED` message, but `TCustomEdit`, which intercepts this, does not use that to limit the text length either.

The only way to prevent this is probably not to assign anything longer than 12 "characters", or to subclass `TCustomEdit` into your own `TMyEdit`, do the check in your own `SetText` procedure, install the component and use that instead.

Comment: Well I guess that asking all the users not to enter more than 12 will not always work, even if I say please. So I will go for option 2 and add this to my subclassed TEdit

Comment: The danger is not that users won't do as you ask, the danger is that you won't. When users enter text, the max. length is enforced. When you assign text in your code, that's when it isn't enforced.

Comment: @GuidoG The SetLength property used only by the UI event handlers, not the property setter methods

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes that is true. In this case its an application on a touch screen and some speedbuttons are used to simulate a keyboard. So every click on such a button adds it's caption to the Text property of the TEdit. That is what they came up with. And so the users are able to enter more than 12. It worked in the test because they used a regular keyboard.... And now this problem came forward they throw it on my desk to fix their issue.

Comment: As @David said, it is up to you to limit the text that is added to the edit by assignment. If you simulate a keyboard with buttons, it is up to you to limit the length of the string you assign to the Text property. Or, as I said, you write your own TEdit descendant which can check that in its SetText method, before doing `inherited Text := TheLimitedString;`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yes I understand, that is what I said in my prior comment. I have it planned now to do in our TEdit descandent. For now I fixed it by not concatinate the Text property anymore in the onClick, but to simulate a keyboard press in the onClick

Comment: @GuidoG: why simulate a key click (which is, IMO, more work), than simply to limit the length of the string on the OnClick (and use one general function for that, don't do it in each OnClick)? Do not add any characters if it is length 12.

Comment: If you used the system on screen keyboard then there'd be no need to do anything

Comment: @RudyVelthuis There is one general function and there is only one onClick that is assigned to all the speedbuttons. Limiting the length there is dificult because it works on the active control, and each can have another maxlength set. That is why my temporary solution works with simulating a keypress so the maxlength of the active control is now used again. But as I said, its a temporary solution until I have time to put this into my subclassed TEdit and replace all TEdits in this app by that one

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Exactly, but unfortunate the developer choose not to use that and now im not allowed to do it like that anymore.

Comment: @GuidoG: Just call it TEdit too and use its unit after StdCtrls. It will then replace the original TEdits. Do the same with TDBEdit.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Thats actually not a bad idea. Fortunate there are only about 20 of them in total so in this case I dont really have to do it like that

Comment: Simulating input is second best to OSK, will take care of possible selection

Comment: This answer sounds like the problem is a design error in VCL. However the property is a reflection of EM_SETLIMITTEXT which exhibits the same behavior as documented.

Comment: @Sertac: even if EM_SETLIMITTEXT exhibits that behaviour, the VCL doesn't have to. The VCL could easily limit the text assigned to the Text property too.

Comment: so it does sounds like a small design error in the VCL ?

Comment: @GuidoG: I don't know if the omission was a design decision or a design error. I would rather have seen it implemented for assignment too, but perhaps Borland (then) decided to keep it in line with EM_SETLIMITTEXT. MS docs say: "The EM_SETLIMITTEXT message limits only the text the user can enter. It does not affect any text already in the edit control when the message is sent, nor does it affect the length of the text copied to the edit control by the WM_SETTEXT message". So it looks more like a design decision by MS.